# How to find out the URL of my search results and edit the columns in the results?

Tags: profile, search-results

Using CiviCRM 5.x and Drupal 7 on localhost.

2 Questions:

1- How to fetch URL that has a full lists of contacts. Right now I can copy they URL, but when I flush the cache the URL changes, so I would need something like Path Auto for this?

2- How to modify the fields the table list view of contact

I'm attaching the screen capture for demonstration purposes:

[image]

Comment: To clarify, this question is not about Drupal Views, but search results and profiles.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can configure profile to use as contact search. You can also control the result columns in profile search. To display contact result by default you can append force=1 in url.

Ref: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#views-for-display-contacts

2. You can create smart group which holds all the contacts and use the contacts link from Manage group page to use as a url.
   [image]
3. Use contact search url and apend force=1 to display contact by default.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Your force=1 worked perfectly,  I can edit columns also, now how to do create a URL to my specific search view criteria? This is the URL http://localhost/crm/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?_qf_Advanced_display=true&qfKey=a8edd2cdbfecc89a638305f96bc3a352_4553

Comment: localhost/crm/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?force=1&reset=1

Answer (score 1):

Answer part of your Question.

You can create a Profile - and then from Adv Search you can specify which
'Views For Display Contacts' to use

> If you are displaying the search results as contacts, you can modify
>   the columns displayed by creating a Profile containing a different set
>   of contact fields and then selecting that Profile here. For example
>   you may want to include columns for Gender and Date of Birth, while
>   eliminating Country. ([learn more](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles)...)